How to determine which method/class is more performant, memory efficient and flexible?
I would say that I am still pretty new to the programming world and I still have much to learn. So during a zoom lecture we had about creating a simple MonoGame Game the teacher stored each Texture in a variable. And I wouldn't say that that's the best approach, you have to add a new variable for each texture. He should have used some kind of data structure, but I am pretty sure he did it because this University course(Game Development, AI, system Development, etc...) starts of by teaching the basics of C#, so you are not supposed to know anything about programming beforehand. I already know some of the basics of the language. Learned it 3 - 4 years ago by my gymnasium teacher and have played around with it ever since.
Anyways I got a new friend in class and he seems to be a lot better at programming than me, been programming 2x more time, dads a programmer etc... So that got me thinking. The solution I had to the problem above was this:
(These examples are in VS instead of MonoGame using a List<string> instead of a List<Textures>)
 public static void LoadTextures(List<string> textures)
 {
     foreach (var texture in textures)
     {
         Textures.Add(texture.Trim());
     }
 }

and I though that worked great. But his solution was this:
    public static void LoadTextures(string textures)
    {
        foreach (var texture in textures.Split(','))
        {
            Textures.Add(texture.Trim());
        }
    }

and in my eyes that solution looked a lot more "clean" than my solution. Spliting up a string instead of using a List, that's pretty cool. I know about the split method, but I never thought of using it here. I guess that comes with experience.
But how do I know which method is best in terms of performance, memory efficiency, flexibility, etc...? I think his solution looks more pleasing to the eye, but which method should be preferred? In my method I used a List and looped through it with the foreach loop. While he used a string, converted the string into an int array and used that array in the foreach loop. So I guess in this case its array vs list, and from my understanding arrays are faster and require less memory than lists, so I guess his method is "better"?

The convention in C# for benchmarking is to use BenchmarkDotNet with a MemoryDiagnoser. Official doc for this scenario here. Make sure to read more on the Getting Started section.

As a side note, I predict that your solution will be faster as it doesn't have to do a call to Split.

Regardless of which is more pleasing to the eye or more efficient, they are completely different. If your input starts off as a comma-delimited string, you're going to have to Split it to get it into a List before calling your version.

profiling

You can compare the two by having logically the same items (comma-separated values on one hand and a list of the same values on the other) to be passed to both and measuring the time required. You can repeatedly call both with the same inputs to solve the issue of variance due to white noise generated by other processes and other aspects that could cause a shift in the measurement.
You can also create two large set of inputs, like testset1, testset2, ... where each testset would represent calling the one with comma-separated values and the other with a list.
However, you can easily foresee that yours will be more performant, because, even though the list items need to be found in the memory by their addresses, his solution expects a string and splits it up (which is a costly operation, because under the hood all separators need to be found and counted, an array needs to be allocated and all tokens from the splitting needs to be individually copied).
So, if you want arrays, then implement the same method with an array as input, like (did not code in C# for many years, excuse me if I have typos):
 public static void LoadTextures(string[] textures)
 {
     foreach (var texture in textures)
     {
         Textures.Add(texture.Trim());
     }
 }

Besides the problem of performance, there is a problem in usability too. Your friend splits a string by a hard-coded separator. Why would that be helpful? What if there is another separator in the string his method receives? And, worse, what if the data-structure was an array or a list in the first place? Will the caller method mash that collection into a comma-separated string? Think about usage, because a method is as much useful as much it can be used.
